# Execute to Line in GDB

Tags: gdb, cgdb

I can execute up to a specific line in GDB by placing a breakpoint there and then pressing `c` to continue execution.

```
b <line_number> ; insert breakpoint
c ; run up to the breakpoint
del <breakpoint_number> ; remove breakpoint
```

Is there a command to run up to a specific line number that will avoid having to run the above sequence of commands?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Still easier is the "until" command, which automatically generates a temporary breakpoint and continues until its location.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found that `u` is a nice shortcut for this.

Comment: You have massively increased my productivity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use temporary breakpoint instead of regular breakpoint. This will eliminate step 3 in your command sequence:

```
(gdb) tbreak <line_number>
(gdb) continue
```

Temporary breakpoint is like regular one except it will be deleted when hit:

```
(gdb) help tbreak 
Set a temporary breakpoint.
Like "break" except the breakpoint is only temporary,
so it will be deleted when hit.  Equivalent to "break" followed
by using "enable delete" on the breakpoint number.
```